# How to handle multiple values returned by Saxon XQuery processor when one value is undefined?

Tags: java, xquery, saxon

I am trying to use the Saxon HE XQuery processor in a Java app to perform ad-hoc queries on XML documents.

For example:

```
for $x in //TestHistory[last()]/results/TestResult
where $x/status = 'TestedFailed'
return (/*/operatorId, 
        $x/status, 
        $x/expectedValue/rawValue, 
        $x/inputValue/rawValue)
```

Here I am gathering 4 values per hit.

The Java code is

```
Processor processor = new Processor(false);
XQueryCompiler compiler = processor.newXQueryCompiler();
XQueryExecutable exec = compiler.compile(query.getQuery());
XQueryEvaluator evaluator = exec.load();

XdmNode xmlDoc = processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(file);
evaluator.setSource(xmlDoc.asSource());

XdmValue eval = evaluator.evaluate();

int idx = 0;
int cols = 4;
int rows = eval.size/cols;
String[][] result = new String[rows][cols];

//foreach item in eval fill array
```

`eval` contains a simple sequence of `XdmItem`s which I can process - assuming that there are 4 items per row.

However, if the node `inputValue/rawValue` has not been defined (which is sometimes the case) there is no corresponding `XdmItem` entry and my processing approach (4 items per row) no longer works.

How can I force each requested attribute to have a corresponding `XdmItem` in the result?

Comment: You could enclose each result in an xml tag. Can you provide a sample input to test on ?

Comment: @Aaron I have wondered about that but wanted to keep it simple. However, it might not be a bad idea: `<r><c name="Expected" type="string">$x/expectedValue/rawValue</c><c `etc...

Comment: You haven't really shown or explained what fails, the `XdmValue eval = evaluator.evaluate();` will give you an `XdmValue`, I don't know what you do afterwards or what the `XQueryResult` type is, but whether you process a sequence of three or four items should not break code trying to process a sequence of an arbitrary number of items. Of course in XQuery 3.1 with arrays and maps you are not bound to work with (always flat) sequences but could e.g. try to return a map with four properties where then on would have an empty sequence as the value.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I added a bit more info to suggest what my approach is and why a problem occurs when an item is not added to the sequence. I wasn't aware of the map possibility but that would be better for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "," operator does sequence concatenation, which means empty sequences get lost: the result of `("a", (), "b")` is `("a", "b")`.

One solution would be to return an array instead of a sequence:

```
return [/*/operatorId, 
        $x/status, 
        $x/expectedValue/rawValue, 
        $x/inputValue/rawValue]
```

You should then be able to cast the result in the Java code to `XdmArray`, and convert this to a Java list of length 4 using `XdmArray.asList()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of returning a sequence of maps with four properties where the value of one property can be an empty sequence:

Input XML:

```
<root id="test-suite1">
  <item>
    <status>passed</status>
    <expected>a</expected>
    <returned>a</returned>
  </item>
  <item>
    <status>failed</status>
    <expected>d</expected>
    <returned>e</returned>
  </item>
 <item>
    <status>failed</status>
    <expected>f</expected>
  </item>
</root>
```

XQuery code:

```
declare namespace output = 'http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization';

declare option output:method 'adaptive';

for $item in root/item
return map {
  'id' : /root/@id => data(),
  'status' : $item/status => data(),
  'expected' : $item/expected => data(),
  'returned' : $item/returned => data()
}
```

Serialized result:

```
map{"returned":"a","status":"passed","expected":"a","id":"test-suite1"}
map{"returned":"e","status":"failed","expected":"d","id":"test-suite1"}
map{"returned":(),"status":"failed","expected":"f","id":"test-suite1"}
```

[Online example](https://martin-honnen.github.io/cheerpj-saxon-worker/index-workbench.html?code=declare%20namespace%20output%20%3D%20%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2010%2Fxslt-xquery-serialization%27%3B%0A%0Adeclare%20option%20output%3Amethod%20%27adaptive%27%3B%0A%0Afor%20%24item%20in%20root%2Fitem%0Areturn%20map%20%7B%0A%20%20%27id%27%20%3A%20%2Froot%2F%40id%20%3D%3E%20data%28%29%2C%0A%20%20%27status%27%20%3A%20%24item%2Fstatus%20%3D%3E%20data%28%29%2C%0A%20%20%27expected%27%20%3A%20%24item%2Fexpected%20%3D%3E%20data%28%29%2C%0A%20%20%27returned%27%20%3A%20%24item%2Freturned%20%3D%3E%20data%28%29%0A%7D%0A&input=%3Croot%20id%3D%22test-suite1%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Citem%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cstatus%3Epassed%3C%2Fstatus%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cexpected%3Ea%3C%2Fexpected%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Creturned%3Ea%3C%2Freturned%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%3Citem%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cstatus%3Efailed%3C%2Fstatus%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cexpected%3Ed%3C%2Fexpected%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Creturned%3Ee%3C%2Freturned%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%3Citem%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cstatus%3Efailed%3C%2Fstatus%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cexpected%3Ef%3C%2Fexpected%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%3C%2Froot%3E%0A&code-type=XQuery&input-type=XML).